# MATLAB: how to split cell arrays of different delimiter numbers?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, split, cell-array

Assume there is an input cell:

`input=`

`"82.3   4.3   John"`

`"4.2    0.0001   Tim Taylor"`

This is a 2by1 cell array. I need to split this to get a 2by3 array like:

`"82.3"   "4.3"   "John"`

`"4.2"   "0.0001"   "Tim Taylor"`

The `split(input)` or `split(input,'\t')` returns error as each row of cell includes different number of delimiters.

Comment: Are data chunks in the cells separated by single tabulation (\t) or by variable number of spaces? Where does the input cell array come from, may be it is possible to import data to produce the result you want.

Comment: @Gryphon They are separated by single tabulation except for the last one where there is a single space between names. I actually need to eliminate single spaces and split only by `\t`. So whenever there is a single space between `x` and `y`, both should form a single item in cell like `x y`.

Comment: `strsplit` may work here, because they are strings

Comment: @gnovice has a great answer. The big thing to note is that '\t' isn't interpreted as tab here, it's kept as a literal. Instead of using char(9) you could do split(input,compose('\t'))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html), but it will differ depending on whether you have a [cell array containing character vectors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html) or a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) containing [strings](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) (I know, it's [very confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42119750/52738)):

If your `input` is displayed like this:

```
input =

  2×1 cell array

    '82.3   4.3 John'
    '4.2    0.0001  Tim Taylor'
```

Then you have a cell array of character vectors, and you can split at the tabs like this:

```
str = split(input, char(9))

str = 

  2×3 string array

    "82.3"    "4.3"       "John"      
    "4.2"     "0.0001"    "Tim Taylor"
```

If your `input` is instead displayed like this:

```
input =

  2×1 cell array

    ["82.3  4.3 John"      ]
    ["4.2   0.0001  Tim Taylor"]
```

Then you have a cell array of strings, and you need to concatenate the cells into a 2-by-1 array of strings before splitting at the tabs:

```
str = split([input{:}].', char(9))

str = 

  2×3 string array

    "82.3"    "4.3"       "John"      
    "4.2"     "0.0001"    "Tim Taylor"
```

Note that I had to use `char(9)` to specify the ASCII tab character, and that the output in each case is a 2-by-3 array of strings.

Comment: Simple and complete answer! Just note that function `split` is relatively new, and you may consider this if you want to make your code work for early matlab.

Answer (score 1):

The are several ways to do that

```
%Never remembered how to correctly insert whitespace characters
inp = {['82.3' char(9) '4.3' char(9) 'John'];['4.2' char(9) '0.0001' char(9) 'Tim Taylor']}
```

1. As @Ander Biguri suggested, with strsplit

   ```
   out=cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,'\t'), inp,'un',0); out=cat(1,out{:})
   ```
2. With some file-import function, i.e. with textscan

   ```
   %with on-the-fly type conversion
   out = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x,'%f%f%s','delimiter','\t'), inp, 'un', 0); out = cat(1,out{:})
   %keeping all values as strings
   out = cellfun(@(x) textscan(x,'%s%s%s','delimiter','\t'), inp, 'un', 0); out = cat(1,out{:})
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is not beautiful, but it does the job:

```
clear output % make sure not exist
for i = 1:size(input,1)
    output(i,:) = cellstr(regexp(input{i}, '\t', 'split'));
end
```

Comment: Please see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html